# Device not managed

Tags: linux, networking, vmware

I have Kali Linux as a VMWare guest in Windows host. The network adapter is in NAT. It was working fine, but when Kali has crashed a reboot was made to the guest OS. Now when it was restarted the IP is not allocated and it is showing `device not managed` in Ethernet Network.

Solutions to a similar issue have been tried and the following configurations were made.

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auth lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Solution 1 : Changing managed to true in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Solution 2: A new conf file for globally managed devices was created using `touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`.

Solution 3: Removing the network adapter and adding it again.

Requirement: Get this back working in NAT

Comment: Close down Kali, open Windows VMware Network Setup, reset overall NAT networking. Restart the computer, open the Kali machine, run sudo apt autoremove, restart when done and see if NAT is working now.

Comment: I posted the above from my Kali 2021.3 guest inside VMware Workstation on a Windows 10 Pro host

Comment: There is no package to remove, and this didn't work. It was working fine all of a sudden after the reboot it went down

Comment: Can you determine what caused Kali to crash and fix that. I am not sure otherwise.

Comment: I don't why it crashed, it was working fine when I tried to access the menu from the panel located at the top, it was stuck and delaying the mouse movements, so I made a restart and it then it ended up with this.

Comment: I have not seen this and out of ideas. Maybe make a new Kali Guest (V2021.3), set it up, make sure it works and then transfer any documents from the old guest (if you can) or a backup.

Comment: That's the only way left, data is not a problem since the shared folder held all the required data.